JUnit integration test fails but Postman test passes with NullPointerException
Please ignore the excessive proliferation of logging.  I'm desperate.  The code below works when I run the application as a Spring Boot Applicant and use Postman to do a PUT with all of the same ApplicantDO data.  I worry that the CompletableFuture might be causing the problem, but I'm new to using it.  To the best of my ability to debug so far, I keep failing in this snippet of code.  I could be wrong though:
 log.info("\n\n\nApplicant converted to a Document: " + document.getString("ssn") + "\n\n\n");
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    try {
        return repository.updateApplicantSync(ssn, document);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error in updateApplicantSync", e);
        throw e;
    }
    }).thenApply(updatedDocument -> {
    if (updatedDocument == null) {
        log.error("No document found with SSN: " + ssn);
        throw new RuntimeException("No document found with SSN: " + ssn);
    }
    log.info("Applicant updated in db: ");
    return converter.convertDocumentToApplicantDO(updatedDocument);
    }).exceptionally(e -> {
    log.debug(messages.getString("error.updating.applicant") + e.getMessage());
    return null;

Failure Trace:
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:152)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.buildAndThrow(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.failNull(AssertNotNull.java:49)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.assertNotNull(AssertNotNull.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull(Assertions.java:312)
    at test.java.loanmarket.borrowingservice.ApplicantServiceTest.testUpdateApplicantAsync(ApplicantServiceTest.java:78)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597)

I have tried so many variations in the test method, but I continually get a updatedApplicant that is null.  Any suggests?
class ApplicantServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private ApplicantRepository repository;
    @Mock
    private MongoDataConverter converter;

    @InjectMocks
    private ApplicantService service;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

  @Test
    void testUpdateApplicantAsync() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    // Arrange
    String ssn = "054220845";
    ApplicantDO applicant = new ApplicantDO();
    applicant.setSSN(ssn);
    applicant.setFirstName("John");
    applicant.setLastName("Doe");
    applicant.setEmail("jpgaber@gmail.com");
    applicant.setPhoneNumber("1234567890");
    applicant.setDateOfBirth(LocalDate.of(1980, 1, 1));
    applicant.setAddress("123 Main St");
    applicant.setEmploymentStatus("Employed");
    applicant.setAnnualIncome(10);
    applicant.setCreditScore(700);
    applicant.setCreditHistory("Good");

    Document document = new Document();
    document.put("ssn", ssn);
    document.put("firstName", "Joe");
    document.put("lastName", "Gaber");
    document.put("email", "jpgaber@gmail.com");
    document.put("phoneNumber", "1234567890");
    document.put("dateOfBirth", LocalDate.of(1980, 1, 1));
    document.put("addressId", "123 Main St");
    document.put("employmentStatus", "Employed");
    document.put("annualIncome", 100000);
    document.put("creditScore", 700);
    document.put("creditHistory", "Good");

    when(converter.convertApplicantDOToDocument(applicant)).thenReturn(document);
    when(repository.updateApplicantSync(ssn, document)).thenReturn(document);

    // Act
    CompletableFuture<ApplicantDO> future = service.updateApplicantAsync(ssn, applicant);
    ApplicantDO updatedApplicant = future.get();

    // Assert
    // assertEquals(ssn, updatedApplicant.getSSN());
    // Assert
    assertNotNull(updatedApplicant, "updatedApplicant is null");
    assertEquals(ssn, updatedApplicant.getSSN());
    }

// Controller class
@PutMapping("/api/v1/loanmarket/applicant/{ssn}")
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ApplicantDO>> updateApplicant(@PathVariable String ssn,
        @RequestBody ApplicantDO applicant) {

    return applicantService.updateApplicantAsync(ssn, applicant).handle((result, ex) -> {
        if (ex != null) {
        log.debug("\n\n" + ex.getMessage() + (result != null ? result.getSSN() : "null") + "\n\n");
        return handleApplicantFailure.apply(ex, result);
        } else if (result == null) {
        log.debug("\n\n Result is null \n\n");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        } else {
        log.debug("\n\n" + messages.getString("returning.response") + "\n\n");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
        }
    });
    }

// Service class
public CompletableFuture<ApplicantDO> updateApplicantAsync(String ssn, ApplicantDO applicant) {
    log.info(messages.getString("entering.updateApplicantAsync"));
    log.info("Applicant to update: " + applicant.getSSN());
    long stamp = lock.writeLock();
    try {
        Document document = converter.convertApplicantDOToDocument(applicant);
        log.info("\n\n\nApplicant converted to a Document: " + document.getString("ssn") + "\n\n\n");
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            return repository.updateApplicantSync(ssn, document);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error in updateApplicantSync", e);
            throw e;
        }
        }).thenApply(updatedDocument -> {
        if (updatedDocument == null) {
            log.error("No document found with SSN: " + ssn);
            throw new RuntimeException("No document found with SSN: " + ssn);
        }
        log.info("Applicant updated in db: ");
        return converter.convertDocumentToApplicantDO(updatedDocument);
        }).exceptionally(e -> {
        log.debug(messages.getString("error.updating.applicant") + e.getMessage());
        return null;
        });
    } finally {
        lock.unlockWrite(stamp);
    }
    }

// Repository class
public Document updateApplicantSync(String ssn, Document document) {

log.debug("\n\n\nEntering updateApplicant\n");
log.debug("\nSSN: " + ssn + "\n");
log.debug("\nDocument: " + document + "\n\n\n");
try {
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("applicants");
    FindOneAndUpdateOptions options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions().returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER);
    Document updatedDocument = collection
    .findOneAndUpdate(Filters.eq("ssn", ssn), new Document("$set", document), options);
    log.debug("Updated Document: " + updatedDocument);
    return updatedDocument;
} catch (MongoException e) {
    log.info("\n\n caught an exception: " + e.getMessage() + "\n\n" + e.getStackTrace().toString());
    log.debug("\n\n" + messages.getString("repository.error.creating.object") + e.getMessage() + "\n\n");
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}

// Utility class for converting between data types
 public ApplicantDO convertDocumentToApplicantDO(Document document) {
    if (document == null) {
        log.error(messages.getString("\n\n\nerror.null.document\n\n\n"));
        throw new NullPointerException(messages.getString("error.null.document"));
    } else if (document.isEmpty()) {
    log.error(messages.getString("\n\n\nerror.empty.document\n\n\n"));
    throw new NullPointerException(messages.getString("error.empty.document"));
    }else {
    log.debug("\n\n\nDocument is not null or empty\n\n\n");
    }

    log.debug(messages.getString("entering.convertDocumentToApplicantDO"));
    ApplicantDO applicant = new ApplicantDO();

    applicant.set_id(document.getObjectId("_id"));

    applicant.setFirstName(Optional.ofNullable(document.getString("firstName")).orElse(""));
    applicant.setLastName(Optional.ofNullable(document.getString("lastName")).orElse(""));
    applicant.setEmail(Optional.ofNullable(document.getString("email")).orElse(""));
    applicant.setPhoneNumber(Optional.ofNullable(document.getString("phoneNumber")).orElse(""));
    applicant.setSSN(Optional.ofNullable(document.getString("ssn")).orElse(""));
    applicant.setDateOfBirth(getLocalDateFromDocument(document, "dateOfBirth")); // This method already handles null
                                             // // values
    applicant.setAddress(Optional.ofNullable(document.getString("addressId")).orElse(""));
    applicant.setEmploymentStatus(Optional.ofNullable(document.getString("employmentStatus")).orElse(""));
    applicant.setAnnualIncome(Optional.ofNullable(document.getInteger("annualIncome")).orElse(0));
    applicant.setCreditScore(Optional.ofNullable(document.getInteger("creditScore")).orElse(0));
    applicant.setCreditHistory(Optional.ofNullable(document.getString("creditHistory")).orElse(""));
    applicant.setLoanApplicationIds(Optional.ofNullable(document.getList("loanApplicationIds", ObjectId.class))
        .orElse(new ArrayList<>()));

    log.info("Successfully converted Document to ApplicantDO");
    log.debug("New ApplicantDO after converting from Document" + applicant.getSSN());

    return applicant;
    }

I've tried other integration tests such as createApplicant and findApplicantBy[some field] and these tests pass.

Have you executed your test with a debugger and checked at each step what values your variables have and when it becomes null? Just by going over each method call in your service code, it becomes clear that you have not stubbed converter.convertDocumentToApplicantDO. Unstubbed methods return a default value for their return type. Unless you have a number, boolean, collection, or an optional, that's going to be null.
